# sql get data from multiple tables and add the result

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL db has a table called `catmaster`. It contains various "categories", each with a unique id like `CAT12`. Each "category" is made up of underlying "keywords" and has its own table with 1 column called `key_id`. So the table `CAT12` might have 4 records (keywords) like the following: `KEY1` `KEY2` `KEY3` `KEY4`. Each of these keywords also has its own table with the same names. Each of these tables has 2 columns, 1 with a date and the other with an integer value, call it inventory.

Is there a way I can write a query that pulls the SUM of the inventory for the underlying keywords (however many there might be) in a given category for a given date?

or is it best to just have my application loop through the records and pull the value for each keyword then sum it itself?

THANKS!

Comment: Better to loop.  You could always create dynamic SQL for this sort of thing.  The best solution of all would be to redesign this database.  It doesn't seem like a good way of doing it.

Comment: I would change the database design to use a table structure like `TABLE table1(category, tag, date, inventory)` with a primary key on `(category, tag)`.  That would get it done on one table.

Comment: that would duplicate way too much data @TrippKinetics.. sounds like the `Inventory` is the same for the `Keyword (KEY1)` no matter what `Catergory` it's tied to.. (Category, Key)  (Key, Inventory, Date) would probably be best way.. but this looks like a case of "I cant change"

Comment: @JamieD77 If the database can't be changed, we just have to hope that none of that data comes from end-users.

Comment: Thanks all. The design can be changed. You're right, @JamieD77, inventory is the same for each keyword regardless of what category it belongs to. And often a keyword will belong to multiple categories. Could you clarify what you mean by your design? Do you mean I should have one table that lists the categories with each respective key (so each category might be repeated in the table hundreds of times for each keyword it owns)? and then another table with repeated keywords for each pair of inventory and date? if so, that second table would get huge as we have thousands of keywords.

Comment: Well if you're telling me you have 1000s of keywords, my assumption is that your current design would mean you'd have 1000s of tables, since each keyword has its own table?

Comment: yea, that's right.  is that bad?